# Add second time series to charts.PerformanceSummary()

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

I am displaying my backtested strategy with the `charts.PerformanceSummary()` function from Performance Analytics. I would like to add a second graph on to the top chart to see how my backtested strategy compares with a benchmark.  So for e.g., my current code is:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)

myEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(c("AAPL","GOOG"), src = "yahoo", from = "2004-04-01", to = "2012-09-30", env = myEnv)
index <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myEnv, Ad), all=TRUE))

index.ret <- (index / lag(index,1) - 1)[-1,]

charts.PerformanceSummary(index.ret[,1])
```

I would like to add `index.ret[,2]` series to the "Cumulative Return" chart, but retain the "Daily Return" and "Drawdown" charts for `index.ret[,1]`.  I am thinking something along the lines of `points()`, as per the base plot function.

Comment: The problem with `charts.PerformanceSummary(index.ret[,1:2])` is that it also puts `index.ret[,2]` on the "Daily Return" and "Drawdown" charts?

Comment: I actually didn't know you could pass two time series into that function - somehow I thought it would return an error.  That actually works fine.  One thing though - it doesn't seem to put `index.ret[,2]` on the "Daily Return" chart, only on the "Drawdown" chart.